# What's the difference between AI_FQDN and AI_CANONNAME results in ADDRINFOW structure?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, networking, dns

In relation to using GetAddrInfoW (I'm coming from a C# usage background).

ADDRINFOW structure can set ai_flags to either AI_FQDN and AI_CANONNAME so that the PWSTR ai_canonname will contain either:

the canonical name registered in DNS
or
the fully qualified domain name that the flat name resolved to

Windows docs:
"the canonical name registered in DNS which may be different than the fully qualified domain name that the flat name resolved to."

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

`ai_canonname` is an out (in c#) parameter kind.

But it can hold either **fully Qualified name** or the **canonical name** based on the flag set (`AI_FQDN`/`AI_CANONNAME`).

*Fully qualified name:* you get the complete path from root level (ex: ru.wikipedia.org.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name#/media/File:DNS-names-ru.svg

*Canonical name:* this is if a domain name is mapped. suppose there is an IP address whose actual domain name is "test.com". But to ensure "www.test.com" to work without fail, a canonical name record is created, so that "www.test.com" points to "test.com".

Answer (score 0):

I believe (but have not checked this) that with `AI_FQDN`, `ai_canonname` is the name that was used in the DNS lookup *after search path processing*.  So if you look up `www` and your search path contains `example.com`, you would get `www.example.com` for a successful lookup in `ai_canonname`, independently of what the DNS says for `www.example.com`.

With the older `AI_CANONNAME` option, the resolver perform search path processing *and* traditional CNAME-based canonicalization. So continuing the first example, if the DNS entry for `www.example.com` is this:

```
www.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1
```

you would again get `www.example.com` in `ai_canonname`. But if the DNS contains this instead:

```
www.example.com. CNAME www1.example.net.
```

and:

```
www.example1.net. IN A 192.0.2.1
```

You would get `www1.example.net` because that is the canonical name at the end of the CNAME change in this case.

The difference makes sense because the canonical name for something that is CDN-hosted is usually completely meaningless (like 
`e8178.e6.cdn-provider.example`), while just applying the search path gives something that is actually meaningful.